# NVIDIA GPU not being used in 23.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, graphics, xorg

I installed Ubuntu 23.10. I have NVIDIA GT 730, which is a legacy card now. While installation, the GDM would not appear, I was only greeted with a black screen. I installed using Safe Graphics Mode. And after installation, I installed Nvidia display driver 470, which is the latest driver from my GPU. I am using Xorg, and under Settings>About>System Details, I can see that Graphics is "NVIDIA GT730" but I don't think it's gnome is using my GPU for display rendering.  Everything's very laggy and slow.

Here is the output of `nvidia-smi`:
[image]

It shows no running process, but while searching for the solution I found that it shows Xorg and gnome-shell under processes for others, meaning GPU is being used for rendering the gnome-shell.

I have tried reinstalling the drivers, what shall I do now ??

Output of `sudo X -version`:

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.7 
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux Dhruv 6.5.0-14-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT DYNAMIC Tue Nov 14 14:59:49 UTC 2023 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic root=UUID=49c34387-1b4a-45d8-a53a-4f15baeb775d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
xorg-server 2:21.1.7-3ubuntu2.4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make sure that you have the latest version
```

Output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "LoadModule"`:

```
(II) LoadModule: "glx" 8.725] 
(II) LoadModule: "nvidia" 8.735] 
(II) LoadModule: "nouveau" 8.739] 
(II) LoadModule: "modesetting" 8.740] 
(II) LoadModule: "fbdev" 8.741] 
(II) LoadModule: "vesa" 8.748] 
(II) LoadModule: "fb" [ 8.748] 
(II) LoadModule: "wfb" [ 8.749] 
(II) LoadModule: "ramdac" 8.751] 
(II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw" 8.753] 
(II) LoadModule: glxserver_nvidia"
(II) LoadModule: "dri2" 9.853] 
(II) LoadModule: "libinput"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested any of this, but I got this on a search I did. "If you want to use that driver with Ubuntu, you'll have to install 20.04 and use the original kernel series only, not the HWE kernel. No later version of Ubuntu supports it in my experience. Anything later than that, you have to use nouveau. I have an old PC with a GT 730 card." [Here](https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=does%20ubuntu%2023.10%20support%20nvidia%20gt%20730%20&fr=yfp-t&fr2=p%3Afp%2Cm%3Asb&ei=UTF-8&fp=1)